# Taurus master shuts down test run when connecting to jmeter slaves in the same network on azure

Tags: jmeter, distributed, taurus

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppmNc.png)

I am running taurus in master node in distributed mode and jmeter in slave node. Slave is running jmeter server properly but master is unable to perform the test. Master instance is able to reach the remote host on the ip but the test plan execution fails. I am pinging bng url in taurus yml scenario.
Below is the jmeter log for reference.

```
13:07:38 ERROR: JMeter log:
2021-10-12 13:07:29,533 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2021-10-12 13:07:29,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/user.properties
2021-10-12 13:07:29,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/system.properties
2021-10-12 13:07:29,551 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading additional properties from: /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107/jmeter-bzt.properties
2021-10-12 13:07:29,551 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting Global properties from the file /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107/jmeter-bzt.properties
2021-10-12 13:07:29,551 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System properties from file: /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107/system.properties
2021-10-12 13:07:29,615 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2020 The Apache Software Foundation
2021-10-12 13:07:29,615 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.4
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_275
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=4.15.0-1113-azure
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=true
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =4294967296
2021-10-12 13:07:29,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =1
2021-10-12 13:07:29,625 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2021-10-12 13:07:29,625 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2021-10-12 13:07:29,625 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4
2021-10-12 13:07:29,625 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/root/bzt
2021-10-12 13:07:29,626 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/root/bzt
2021-10-12 13:07:29,626 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 10.97.104.71 Name: wk-caas-72db06a10f1e40fba0235dcea9465aaf-bd09aa1593d47434818635 FullName: wk-caas-72db06a10f1e40fba0235dcea9465aaf-bd09aa1593d47434818635
2021-10-12 13:07:29,626 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.classpath=/root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107:/root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107
2021-10-12 13:07:29,626 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Adding to classpath and loader: /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107
2021-10-12 13:07:29,627 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Adding to classpath and loader: /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107
2021-10-12 13:07:29,635 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/root/bzt'
2021-10-12 13:07:29,636 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107'
2021-10-12 13:07:29,963 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2021-10-12 13:07:30,057 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2021-10-12 13:07:30,063 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2021-10-12 13:07:30,072 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107/modified_requests.jmx
2021-10-12 13:07:30,144 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET]
2021-10-12 13:07:30,146 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
2021-10-12 13:07:30,226 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-10-12 13:07:30,226 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-10-12 13:07:30,226 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-10-12 13:07:30,226 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-10-12 13:07:30,226 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2021-10-12 13:07:30,227 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2021-10-12 13:07:30,339 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.97.104.70:1099
2021-10-12 13:07:30,341 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:30,421 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting distributed test with remote engines: [10.97.104.70:1099] @ Tue Oct 12 13:07:30 GMT 2021 (1634044050419)
2021-10-12 13:07:30,421 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2021-10-12 13:07:30,427 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2021-10-12 13:07:30,427 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2021-10-12 13:07:31,313 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:31,313 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:31,316 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-10-12 13:07:31,323 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2021-10-12 13:07:31,323 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2021-10-12 13:07:31,323 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:31,323 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:31,324 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2021-10-12 13:07:31,324 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2021-10-12 13:07:31,325 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:31,325 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:32,217 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:32,217 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2021-10-12 13:07:32,350 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 10.97.104.70:1099 basedir='2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107'
2021-10-12 13:07:32,351 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {user.classpath=/root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107:/root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107, jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true, jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms, summariser.name=, sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8, jmeterengine.nongui.port=4445, client.rmi.localport=1099, jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true, jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true, server.rmi.ssl.disable=True, loops=10, rampup=10, jmeterengine.nongui.maxport=4445, threads=2}
2021-10-12 13:07:32,423 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 10.97.104.70:1099
2021-10-12 13:07:32,423 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started:[10.97.104.70:1099]
2021-10-12 13:07:32,439 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Started remote host:  10.97.104.70:1099 (1634044052439)
2021-10-12 13:07:32,561 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Finished remote host: 10.97.104.70:1099 (1634044052561)
2021-10-12 13:07:32,561 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: All remote engines have ended test, starting RemoteTestStopper thread
2021-10-12 13:07:37,565 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Interrupting RMI Reaper
13:07:38 INFO: Artifacts dir: /root/bzt/2021-10-12_13-07-24.364107
13:07:38 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-10-12 13:07:32,439 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Started remote host:  10.97.104.70:1099 (1634044052439)
2021-10-12 13:07:32,561 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Finished remote host: 10.97.104.70:1099 (1634044052561)
```

1. Are you sure that your test is supposed to finish in 122 milliseconds?
2. If yes, are you sure that the slave can reach the master in order to transfer the results back?

Make sure that you can connect from the slave to the port you define as the `client.rmi.localport`, this port is open in [OS firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) and in [Azure Network Security Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview), etc.

Also [jmeter-server.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) from the slave should contain some information regarding the failure.

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) - there you can see how and what ports to open and how to specify the ports on the master and slaves